# Add class on scrolldown and replace class when class is added

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to have the class `.socialtrans2` replace the class `.socialtrans` when the class `.navbg` is added via the JavaScript function `addnavbg`, and revert those changes when class `.navbg` is removed, but I don't know how.

```js
    document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML =
      "<ul id='menu'>" +
      "<li><a class='regular' href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +
      "<li><a class='regular' href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +
      "<li><a class='regular' href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +
      "<li><a class='regular' href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +
      "<li><a class='regular' href='Placeholder1.html'>Placeholder1</a></li>" +
      "<li><a class='social' href='instagram.html'><span class='socialtrans'></span><img src='graphics/Instagram_App_Large_May2016_200.png' alt='instagram'></a></li>" +
      "<li><a class='social' href='youtube.html'><span class='socialtrans'></span><img src='graphics/YouTube-logo-full_color.png' alt='youtube'></a></li>" +
      "<li><a class='social' href='soundloud.html'><span class='socialtrans'></span><img src='graphics/soundcloud-icon.png' alt='soundcloud'></a></li>"
    "</ul>";

    function setActive() {
      aObj = document.getElementById('nav01').getElementsByTagName('a');
      for (i = 0; i < aObj.length; i++) {
        if (document.location.href.indexOf(aObj[i].href) >= 0) {
          aObj[i].className = 'active';
        }
      }
    }

    window.onload = setActive;

    window.onscroll = function() {
      addnavbg()
    };

    function addnavbg() {
      if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 300) {
        document.getElementById('menu').className = 'navbg';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('menu').className = '';
      }
    }
```

```css
/* navigation */

ul#menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear;
}
.navbg {
  background-color: #424242;
}
ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
}
ul#menu li a {
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FF0000;
}
ul#menu a.regular:link {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
ul#menu li a.active {
  color: #ff0000;
}
/* social media links */

ul#menu a.social:link {
  border: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  float: right;
}
ul#menu a.social.link:hover {
  display: inline-block;
}
span.socialtrans {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
span.socialtrans:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
span.socialtrans2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: right;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
span.socialtrans2:hover {
  background-color: #424242;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav01"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest changing your css.  Assuming that you don't need socialtrans2 for any other reasons besides the look.

```html
//takes precedence when navbg is not set
span.socialtrans{
}
span.socialtrans:hover{
}

//takes precedence when navbg is set
.navbg span.socialtrans{
}
.navbg span.socialtrans:hover{
}
```

A cool thing about css is that a more defined a css "path" takes precedence.  So when navbg is not there, the first css will happen.   While navbg is there, the second will happen.

```html
<!--first css in above example happens in this case-->
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a><span class="socialtrans"></span></a></li>
</ul>
<!--second css in above example happens in this case-->
<ul id="menu" class="navbg">
  <li><a><span class="socialtrans"></span></a></lis>
</ul>
```

Comment: If I am understanding you then this should still work.  In my example those two css cases do not happen at the same time.  The more defined it is, the more id classes and types you have, the higher precedence it takes.

Comment: The thing is socialtrans puts a white bg over the sociallinks  (they're image links) which fades in as hover and socialtrans 2 is supposed to put a grey one over it because navbg is grey and I don't want to have small white squares over my sociallinks .

Comment: thanks alot curtainrising your solution helped me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to replace 'socialtrans' with 'socialtrans2' on each < span >

```
function addnavbg() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 300 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 300) {
        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
        menu.className = 'navbg';
        var spans = menu.getElementsByTagName('span');
        for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
            if (spans[i].className == 'socialtrans') {
                spans[i].className = 'socialtrans2';
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
        menu.className = '';
        var spans = menu.getElementsByTagName('span');
        for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
            if (spans[i].className == 'socialtrans2') {
                spans[i].className = 'socialtrans';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Curtainrising's answer is much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Is This what your looking for? This can be achieved easily with jQuery

```
var navbg = $('.navbg');
var menu = $('.menu');
var s = $('.socialtrans');
var s2 = $('.socialtrans2');

if(menu.hasClass(navbg)){
  menu.removeClass(s);
  menu.addClass(s2);
}else{
  menu.removeClass(s2);
  menu.addClass(s);
}
```